# Upgrade 8.4.8 to 8.5.11 error Inspector not found

Tags: 8

I'm trying to upgrade from Drupal 8.4.8 to Drupal 8.5.11 but I'm stuck on the following error

```
    Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                [error]
Error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Plugin\Inspector' not found in docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/DefaultPluginManager.php:151
```

Here's the steps I ran:

```
1. composer remove drupal/console

2. composer require acquia/blt:8.9.15 acquia/lightning:~3.1.0 --no-update

3. Add the following code to the "conflict" section of composer.json file.
"drupal/core": ">=8.6.0"

4. composer update acquia/blt dmore/chrome-mink-driver acquia/lightning drupal/core cweagans/composer-patches "symfony/*" --with-all-dependencies

5. drush updb -y
```

The error show up when I ran the step number 5 (drush updb -y)

Comment: Why are you trying to upgrade to 8.5.11 in the first place?  8.5.11 was released in February of last year. There has been many security updates since then... the latest stable version as of this writing is 8.8.4

Comment: that's right, but I'm using blt and lightning which require a version by version upgrade instead of jump right to the latest.